# Why does this run-time error keep poping up?

Tags: python

So here's my code, and "name 'player' is not defined" pops up when playing the game. This is only a practice project so the entire code is attached. I've been trying to finish the code posted in 100 Days of Complete Python Pro Boot Camp, and got stuck on day 11. Someone plz help me XD.

```
......

def main():
    player = [random.choice(cards), random.choice(cards)]
    comp = [random.choice(cards), random.choice(cards)]
    player_total = player[0] + player[1]
    comp_total = comp[0] + comp[1]
    ace_count = 0
    ace_position = []
    comp_ace = 0
    comp_ace_position = []
    no = False
    
    print_deck(player, comp, player_total)
    
    if player_total == 21:
        print_final(player, comp, player_total, comp_total)
        print("Win with a Blackjack ")
        return
    elif comp_total == 21:
        print_final(player, comp, player_total, comp_total)
        print("Lose, opponent has Blackjack ")
        return
    
    def deal():
        global player, player_total, comp, comp_total, ace_count, ace_position, comp_ace, comp_ace_position, no
        
        deal = input("Type 'y' to get another card, type 'n' to pass: ")

        if deal == 'y':
            new_card = random.choice(cards)
            player.append(new_card)
            player_total += new_card

            if new_card == 11:
                ace_count += 1
                ace_position.append(len(player - 1))

            while player_total > 21:
                if ace_count > 0:
                    player_total -= 10
                    player[ace_position[0]] -= 10
                    ace_position.remove(ace_position[0])
                else:
                    print_deck(player, comp, player_total)
                    comp_move()

                    print("You went over. You lose ")
                    break   
                
            print_deck(player, comp, player_total)
        else:
            comp_move()

            if player_total == comp_total:
                print("Draw ")
            elif player_total > comp_total:
                print("You win ")
            else:
                print("You lose ")
            
            no = True
......
```

Comment: Without complete code it's difficult to help you. And what have you tried ?

Answer (score 1):

This is to do with the scope of where player exist. Notice the nested function definition. - When you nest a function inside another all the local variable of the parent function are global of the child.

What you have done here is declared a global variable within deal() which is not needed, this raises the error as python is expecting a value to be assigned to that new global variable.

To fix: simply remove the variable that declares them all as globals.

p.s. I feel this may not be the best explanation feel free to ask questons.